# How to GZIP google maps

Tags: google-maps, gzip

I understand GZIP is done using the client and can be done in 1 mouse-click, but I can't find any useful documentation or explanation anywhere about how to gzip a google maps iFrame displayed on a website.

All I can find is this - https://developers.google.com/google-apps/tasks/performance - and then I don't have the knowledge or experience to know how to implement this properly, and I would greatly appreciate anyone who has had experience in this who could help.

Answer (score 0):

Related to the linked explanation, you browser must send these 2 headers:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip
User-Agent: my program (gzip)
```

- **Accept-Encoding:** be sure that your browser supports gzip(I would say when your browser isn't older than 15 years, you don't need to do anything, he will support GZIP and already sends this header)
- **User-Agent:** it depends on the used browser how to apply it. In Firefox you must modify the setting `general.useragent.override` and set it to the desired string(e.g. `Firefox(gzip)`) . Type `about:config` in the adressbar, search for the setting and modify it.

But usually you don't need to change anything when you use a common browser, the maps already will be delivered in GZIP(the article is related to google-apps)

**Note:** It may have side-effects when you modify the userAgent-string. Many websites use this string to detect the browser and deliver content based on the result.